# Upload a file to a server using .aspx pages (VB)

Tags: php, asp.net, html, iis

I'm currently developing an application in .aspx pages which use VB Script on an IIS server. I need to upload an image in one of my HTML forms. Currently the code uses `Form.Request("field_name")` to get the data from the text fields.

I would like to know if there is an ASP equivalent of PHP's `$_FILES` as I can't seem to find anything on the web that's remotely linked to what I need to do, all of the scripts I find are either hugely overcomplicated for such a simple task, or show how to upload a file using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Request.Files`

```
For Each item As HttpPostedFile In Request.Files

    <Deal with files here>

Next
```

More Info: [Uploading Files in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx)